# Retrofit 2 swagger response is 200 but can not get token from response body

Tags: authentication, retrofit, swagger, token

**I try to get connect and get token with Retrofit 2 from a swagger restful service ,I get the response is 200 but can not get token from response body**

```
private void login() {
        Call<User> call=userClient.login("user","123","password");

        call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {

                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    token=response.body().getToken();
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,token,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"login not correct",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {

                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: have you tried logging the value of `response` ?

Comment: Response is : Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=200, message=OK, url=http://example.com/webapiapplication/token}.

Comment: what is the value of `response.body()`

Comment: I used postman and get the result and token nothing seems unnormal but when try it with my application ,my token is null  as a response

Comment: copy the response from postman and show it here

Comment: Result ={User@5193}
 email=null
 İd =0
 token=null
 Shadow$_klass_=class com.example.examplemobileandroid.main.model.User
Shadow$_monitor_=-2084580109

Comment: POSTMAN RESPONSE :{
    "access_token": "TkUKSr0L4dQI4ihz7raAmrHnQ2MeToAI0urW4iuYbsuxOJr19bGzYyHBctl9BN9OPRbEY5VlhF2SmJ2s7WYEwJrW4FCUqq4w6S-oKAmS9B4DBIcKKnFNQGOmxagM0z6DYkWMbaoNZe6UWR4NDQNcSmJETcpPyScwsFnkxGFlwhIRwKkLVUnxAB_JzQE_zCQpA5BsE56p7_rw0CWi4VQKYiP-xfo2nBhWNYPVyrBlHhLvxnZZ05eiO02raqE11Cj0Wo-saAclQ5Ex651TQ2aIYA",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "expires_in": 86399
}

Comment: create model class like below added answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the User class like this

```
 public class User {

@SerializedName("access_token")
@Expose
private String accessToken;
@SerializedName("token_type")
@Expose
private String tokenType;
@SerializedName("expires_in")
@Expose
private Integer expiresIn;

public String getAccessToken() {
return accessToken;
}

public void setAccessToken(String accessToken) {
this.accessToken = accessToken;
}

public String getTokenType() {
return tokenType;
}

public void setTokenType(String tokenType) {
this.tokenType = tokenType;
}

public Integer getExpiresIn() {
return expiresIn;
}

public void setExpiresIn(Integer expiresIn) {
this.expiresIn = expiresIn;
}

}
```

and then try like this

```
token=response.body().getAccessToken();
```

Your retrofit instance should be like

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Constants.your_baseUrl)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
```

Comment: Thank you so much it works , my user model was not correct format

Comment: great, happy to help!